# Retrofit2 POST запрос с параметрами

Tags: php, java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

Использую Retrofit2, хочу отправить на сервер POST параметры.

```
public interface ServerApi {
@GET("Singleton")
Call<String> getJSON();

@POST("Singleton")
Call<String> senDDudes(@Query("author") String author);
}
```

Использую этот интерфейс для отправки данных. При заходе на сервер данные получаются в POST формате, а потом возвращаются в JSON формате.

```
 Retrofit rt;
    rt=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2/").addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    ServerApi sapi=rt.create(ServerApi.class);
    Call<String> msg=sapi.senDDudes("Dude","bude");
    msg.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

            System.out.println(response.body().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t.toString());

        }
    });
```

Проблема в том, что данные в виде POST не приходят на сервер. Возврат есть, а вот приема нет. Проверяю с помощью echo $_POST['author'] на самом сервере.

**НО** если я использую вместо аннотации @POST аннотацию @GET, и вывожу соответственно echo $_GET['author'], данные выводятся.

***В Retrofit я новичок, поэтому учитывайте пожалуйста это.***

Answer (score 1):

Параметр с аннотацией `@Query` управляет параметрами `query` запроса (как ни странно). Поэтому в php вы этот параметр можете достать с помощью `$_GET` (как известно, `GET` запрос не имеет тела, и логично что параметры запроса достаются из query `url`-a).

Чтобы отправить тело с `POST`-запросом:

```
interface Foo {

    // Вся соль здесь
    @POST("/path")
    FooResponse postJson(@Body FooRequest body);
}
```

Класс десериализованного тела запроса:

```
public class FooRequest {
  final String foo;
  final String bar;

  FooRequest(String foo, String bar) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

Делаете запрос:

```
FooResponse = foo.postJson(new FooRequest("kit", "kat"));
```

Comment: То есть я правильно понимаю, что получать данные $_POST['data'] я не смогу?

Comment: @Дмитрий сделайте как в ответе и попробуйте.

Comment: Используйте связки `GET + Query`, `POST + Body` и не будет путаницы при приеме.